# Rest API ACCEPT and Content-Type

Tags: php, android, json, api, rest

I was trying to hit a rest API URL which using POST request. It receives "`ACCEPT`" as "`application/json`" and "`Content-Type`" as "`application/xml`". The response from sever says "`Content-Type → application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8`". But what now am getting is some kind of encrypted text as below

```
N4+8ByEFqdMY+fgXAeMQIe93TUKGNXerqeWOGDWm3IoDK5j7YysPB93ebN3IOBCOXlSOlkOV7Vr6 Cz0+nQnWVp09OmB1Xbazz33uWZrJqzzZ8Z7Zdnj0ZfIWMPKDKrymhR8SbXODr+DPj2b3Mv6kI8uo Q3Bx+AtQ8pCVqZQ5sutIOGvJdLhHNSLDNoWZOs87i3eDjGUobNUEiJFaavfKF7l4XJTtVng2TAqN VU9SF5PAlq16syqxTQ2qdk/NU+BOBv8mIYpoCn5gRhuNgpqyPI3b/EhRHLTCo23gRSTi6vwPHeQf vLLTEqtXJnE80xRNyRc9/XvnxBXzaCuW5JJ19GtBzzeJjRwf79WxFbdR50KTgt98T4fpzT42BWJa 6E7w/D7kH+kPO4GkhR6pB7JsC/PBxahvFsEV2tR1dQpCtWQUI9nmMt85bazfRwY4zOWWS5I/rZdN snKn2Zq+Xc2nzIG+imbAoSjIlp8+m/FSzB5fezLHF91fwTM/D1oDUaia11uLtqN8s1pHaH4K8Vkm Ll6pT5KEe+wqZD92gYiEButwXJpxKW4lEhTRdUtffU/6
```

How can I read it into plain text for some form of readable text like JSON or XML?

Comment: content-type: application/octet-stream, means it is a binary file (bytes array) and you should download it or use other application to open it.

Answer (score 0):

try using below line:-

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Comment: Tired. But not working, still getting the above response.

Comment: is it returning some kind for file?

Comment: Yes, you definitely want to write something that will change the character encoding. I assume that text actually has a valid value and isn't just a server error.

Comment: Yes, the response has some valid text behind. But how can I decode it